# React Native LinkedIn Authentication

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

Hi I am an beginner to React native. I am trying to implement LinkedIn login to react native mobile application I could not find proper package or plugin. If anyone who has done this before please help me with the steps to follow. I refer some packages they are,

1. react-native-linkedin-oauth (no proper documentation provided)
2. react-native-linkedin (facing error in webview when login)
3. react-native-linkedin-sdk

Answer (score 0):

have you installed [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview)?? if not then install it first and then use **react-native-linkedin**

Comment: this is not answer.. can you comment under question instead posting comment as answer? @Hameer